# How to load block class within other block in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, blocks

I want to load my grid class within constructor method of other block.I try this peace of code but don't succeed.

```
`class Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_View_Tabs  extends 
    Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Abstract
        implements Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Tab_Interface
    {

        protected $_chat = null;

        protected function _construct()
        {
            parent::_construct();
               $class = Mage::getConfig()->getBlockClassName('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_tab_tickethistory');   
                $block = new $class;
               $block-> _prepareCollection();

        }
    } .
```

I can set phtml file here but my requirement is to load grid class.how can i do that ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can load a block like this:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('identifier/here');
```

in your case:

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('mymodule/adminhtml_mymodule_edit_tab_tickethistory');
```

but what you are trying to do won't work because `_prepareCollection()` is a protected method. You can only call it inside the class methods or it's descendants.
I think it's better to explain the problem you have, not the problems you have while implementing the solution. Maybe someone has a better idea on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your respons.If you look at my question (" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187278/rewrite-or-add-custom-tab-to-the-sales-order-view-in-magento/17188099?noredirect=1#comment24890528_17188099").I solve it .After that I face current problem that how can now load grid instead of phtml.Hope you got point